# The best way to programmatically rename a file during document loading in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

**Problem**
Change the content of the file, add an extension to its name, add a Icon Overlay and further metadata when uploading a document to a Document Library in SharePoint 2013.

**Solution**
In a farm solution for SP2013 I added an event receiver for Document Libraries. 
In Item Added method I wrote the logic to make the changes required to the item

The logic includes the reading of SPFile from incoming parameter properties.ListItem.File to which the contents are modified through the byte array read by SPFile.OpenBinary and subsequently saved by SPFile.SaveBynary. After that SPFile.MoveTo moves the file to the same location but with an added extension to the file name: rename a file we might say.
While running ItemAdded everything works properly, but when the new item is displayed in AllItems.aspx page changes do not reflect at all what happened earlier in event receiver.
To be honest I have noticed two different behaviors depending on whether the event receiver is called Asynchronous or Synchronous in element.xml

**Asynchronous**
The file appears "as was", that is, the changes made by ItemAdded seem to have been discarded. Clicking on the file appeared on the list an error page "Page not found 404” is immediately displayed. Returning to AllItems page, so recharging it, appear the new name of the file, the new content, the new overlayed icon and clicking the link opens the file with the new content.

**Synchronous**
After running ItemAdded, client-side, in the window that tracks the load ("This should not take long ...") appears an exception of type FileNotFoundException. By closing this window the new item does not appear in the list. Doing F5 to reload the page AllItems the new item appears as rightly modified by ItemAdded.

In both cases also it happens something else wrong.
Assuming the loading of "File0001.txt" file and adding "xyz" extension, properly registered with the appropriate icon in the appropriate XML file, to get a "File0001.txt.xyz" file, the name displayed in the list appears to be " File0001.txt "and going to review the property file name is transformed into" File0001.xyz ", losing the original extension.
Passing a lot of time looking for examples, I have not found anything that comes close to my needs.

At this point I looked for a way to reload the page at the end of ItemAdded, but this generates a System.Web.HttpException type error: Can not redirect after HTTP headers sono stati sent.

What I want to know is if ItemAdded I make a mistake in the code, or, the strategy adopted by me is incorrect, while being inspired by an old code written for SP2010 and running.

I thought of a Workflow, for a Web Part, or even to use the new Add-in, but I'm undecided because what I write is in fact a "plug-in" that must have impact "0" on the environment where it will be installed.

Can someone kindly help me.